# CTAssetsPickerController adding a checkmark

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I've been trying to add check mark when asset is selected.
Here is the Framework's GIT rep https://github.com/chiunam/CTAssetsPickerController

I can't find a way to add it and also change the background color.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for future people in need looking at this:

Go to: https://github.com/asivura/CTAssetsPickerController

Download it as zip

Get to your target (your project)

Right-clic: Add files to "Project Name"

Look for your Download directory

Look for the unziped asivura/CTAssetsPickerController directory

Enter CTAssetsPickerController directory

Select the file: CTAssetsPickerController.bundle and import it

Make sure in your Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Ressources that 
CTAssetsPickerController.bundle is imported else import it (it should be imported at the moment your select and import the file)

Compile then launch, you should see the checkmark and other images missing.

Comment: Thaks for response, I solved this on December:) point was to customize check marks, I can post solution if you want